# Server socket file transfer

Tags: java, serversocket

I have used server socket concept in java to transfer files like images and videos. But when i receive at the client side, i am customizing the file names. Can i get the original name of the file as it is?

For Example:

If the file from server end for transfer is "abc.txt", i need this same name to be reflected in the client end(without passing the name separately).

In the server end:

```
public class FileServer {
  public static void main (String [] args ) throws Exception {
    // create socket
    ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(13267);
    while (true) {
      System.out.println("Waiting...");

      Socket sock = servsock.accept();
      System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);
      OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
    new FileServer().send(os);
      sock.close();
      }
    }

  public void send(OutputStream os) throws Exception{
      // sendfile
      File myFile = new File ("C:\\User\\Documents\\abc.png");
      byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()+1];
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
      bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
      System.out.println("Sending...");
      os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
      os.flush();
  }
}
```

In the client end:

```
    public class FileClient{
  public static void main (String [] args ) throws Exception {


    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();


    // localhost for testing
    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1",13267);
    System.out.println("Connecting...");
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    // receive file
    new FileClient().receiveFile(is);
       long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end-start);

    sock.close();
  }

  public void receiveFile(InputStream is) throws Exception{
      int filesize=6022386;
      int bytesRead;
      int current = 0;
      byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("def");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
        current = bytesRead;


        do {
           bytesRead =
              is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
           if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
        } while(bytesRead > -1);

        bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply transfer the metadata (in your case `myFile.getName()`) before the actual file contents, and make client and server read and emit that metadata. It's a good idea to use established protocols, for example [HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) and its [`Content-Disposition`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) header.

Comment: But the thing is that im sending an array of files like that to client. Can't i append the name of the file to the byte array of the file. If yes, please tell me how to do it.

Comment: @Arun Sure you can, you just need to devise a protocol. What serialization method/protocol are you using? Including the code that actually send or receives the files (<15 lines) in the question would be of great help.

Comment: I have editted my question with the full source code. This is actually taken from the links posted in this question. Kindly help me. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @Arun No offense, but this looks a bit like homework, so I won't include a full solution here, but also point to an educational instead of a practical solution (i.e. HTTP). You'll have to design your own protocol, which should include the file size and name. Try the following format: `4 bytes for the file size` `4 byte of file name length` `file name as byte[]`. You can convert the filename to bytes with `myFile.getName().getBytes("UTF-8")`. By the way: What is the rationale behind the `+1` in `new byte [(int)myFile.length()+1]`?

Comment: oh sorry phihag, i tried to add an extra element to the byte array, later in the code. that i removed. Thanks for your valuable thought.

Answer (score 4):

For the receiver to know the file name, either:

a) it must assume it knows the name because it asked for it,

b) the server sends the name first as part of the stream.

If you invent a way to send information without actually sending it, let me know and we can become billionaires. We can call it 'computer telepathy'.

Comment: I m sending a the file as a byte array to the client. Please temme one thing... will it contain the name of the file or not??

Comment: It will contain the name if you send the name, otherwise it is unlikely the file will contain its own name.

Answer (score 1):

see this references,May be helpful...

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0542.html

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/TransferafileviaSocket.htm

http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=1&thread=34857

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to do this. Just wrap your input stream inside DataInputStream and use methods like .writeUTF(myFile.getName()). Similarly, you can read file name at receiver by applying .readUTF on DataInputStream. Here is a sample code:
Sender:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);  
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    OutputStream os;
    try {
        os = socket.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
        dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());  
.............////// catch exceptions
```

Receiver:

```
InputStream in;
    try {
        bufferSize=socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
        in=socket.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);
        String fileName = clientData.readUTF();
        System.out.println(fileName);
................../////// catch exceptions
```